# I need to filter a table using dax command or other power bi methods

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to filter the table so it can look like the image.

[image]

I need to filter out the table so that if (leave*3)<remain only those outputs should be shown.
I tried to use a calculated column and used dax:

```
remain_find = 
var remaining = Voting[Remain] 
return IF(Voting[3 x leave] < remaining, remaining)
```

But it shows blank where the condition fails. I need to do this without any blanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add your measure to the filters of the Visual.

Set the filter on the measure to exclude blanks:

[image]